# What is the meaning of saying that conformal $f$ preserves angles?

Tags: complex-analysis

Recall that a map $f:U \to V$  between domains $U,V  \subset \mathbb C$ is called Conformal if $f$ is homomorphic and injective.

> What is the meaning of saying conformal map $f$ preserve angle and how does one prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B\subset U$ be two curves which intersect. We can draw tangents at intersection point and measure the angle between the tangent lines; this is the angle between those two curves lying in $U$.
Now apply $f$ and see the image curves $f(A), f(B)\subset V$. If these two curves have the same angle as $A,B$ we say $f$ preserves the angles (this should happen for any two curves lying in $U$. )

Comment: Thank you..is it obvious that holomorphic injective map satisfy this property?

Comment: Holomorphic and locally injective is enough. That is derivative not zero. It is in textbooks on complex analysis.

Comment: How does one see it if derivative is nonzero? I know derivative of $f$ will be nonzero if holomorphic and injective.Any reference?